# Use mod_proxy to change port to url apache2

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I'm running NodeBB a forum which runs on port 4567 and I need it to be redirected to https and have the port removed on the end. I've looked around but nothing has worked. This is what I've tried:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>

ProxyPass         /  https://forum.website.net:4567
ProxyPassReverse  /  https://forum.website.net:4567
```

I want the end URL to look like this: https://forum.website.net.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a slight error.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>

ProxyPass         /  https://forum.website.net:4567
ProxyPassReverse  /  https://forum.website.net:4567
```